# how to export networkx graph to javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps-api-3, networkx

I have a networkx graph which contains nodes whose positions in the graph are real world latitude and longitudes which I want to use with google maps.

How do I export this graph using python for e.g. in JSON format?

Comment: provide an example of the information which is stored in node. For example, ({'latitude': 50.03, 'longitude':40.47}) or ('latitude: 50.03, longitude: 40.47') 

and yep, as @JohnHartsock asked, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one format.  You can see some examples of how to write some of them with NetworkX at http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/readwrite.json_graph.html

If you need something different, the Python code is pretty simple to modify.

Comment: Dead link, answer isn't valid anymore